# matplotlib: get the subplot layout?

Tags: layout, matplotlib, figure, subplot

I have a function that creates a grid of similar 2D histograms. So that I can select whether to put this new plot on a pre-existing figure, I do the following:

```
def make_hist2d(x, y, current_fig=False, layout=(1,1,1),*args):

    if current_fig: 

        fig = _plt.gcf()
        ax  = fig.add_subplot(*layout)  # layout=(nrows, ncols, nplot)

    else:

        fig, ax = _plt.subplots()    


    H, x, y = np.histogram2d(...)

    # manipulate the histogram, e.g. column normalize.

    XX, YY = _np.meshgrid(xedges, yedges)
    Image  = ax.pcolormesh(XX, YY, Hplot.T, norm=norm, **pcmesh_kwargs)
    ax.autoscale(tight=True)

    grid_kargs = {'orientation': 'vertical'}
    cax, kw    = _mpl.colorbar.make_axes_gridspec(ax, **grid_kargs)
    cbar       = fig.colorbar(Image, cax=cax)
    cbar.set_label(cbar_title)

    return fig, ax, cbar



def hist2d_grid(data_dict, key_pairs, layout, *args):  # ``*args`` are things like xlog, ylog, xlabel, etc. 
                                                       # that are common to all subplots in the figure.

    fig, ax = _plt.subplots()    

    nplots = range(len(key_pairs) + 1)    # key_pairs = ((k1a, k1b), (k2a, k2b), ..., (kna, knb))

    ax_list = []

    for pair, i in zip(key_pairs, nplots):

        fig, ax, cbar = make_hist2d(data[k1a], data[k1b]

        ax_list.append(ax)

    return fig, ax_list
```

Then I call something like:

```
hgrid = hist2d_grid(...)
```

However, if I want to add a new figure to the `grid`, I don't know of a good way to get the subplot layout. For example, is there something like:

```
layout = fig.get_layout()
```

That would give me something like `(nrows, ncols, n_subplots)`?

I could do this with something like:

```
n_plot = len(ax_list) / 2  # Each subplot generates a plot and a color bar.
n_rows = np.floor(np.sqrt(n_ax))
n_cols = np.ceil(np.sqrt(n_ax))
```

But I have to deal with special cases like a `(2,4)` subplot array for which I would get `n_rows = 2` and `n_cols = 3`, which means that I would be passing `(2,3,8)` to `ax.add_subplot()`, which clearly doesn't work because 8 > 3*2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `ax` returned by `fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,2)` is a numpy array of axes, then `ax.shape` will give you the layout information you want, e.g.

```
 nrows, ncols = ax.shape
 n_subplots = nrows*ncols
```

You can also get the locations of the various axes by looping over the children of the figure object,

```
[[f.colNum, f.rowNum] for f in fig.get_children()[1:]]
```

and probably get the size from the final element `fig.get_children()[-1]`

You could also use [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) to be more explicit about the location of subplots if needed. With gridspec you setup the gridspec object and pass to subplot,

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
```

To get the layout you can then use,

```
gs.get_geometry()
```

Comment: Good point. I can set up a `gridspec` and only add axes as needed.